# How do I have multiple unique has_one associations of the same type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationships, has-one

I am making a ruby app that will track ping pong game stats. This is what the model for my player looks like so far

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base

#has one winner
has_one :winner,
:source => :user

#has one loser
has_one :loser,
    :source => :user


belongs_to :player
alias :recorded_by :player

end
```

When I load the page though, I get an error saying "unknown key: source." If you cannot tell what I am doing, the model is supposed to contain two user objects, one labeled "winner" and one labeled "loser." Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

try `has_one :loser, :class_name => 'User'` this is needed because rails can't guess the correct model for loser_id

`:source` on the other hand is used in :through relations.

Comment: I've tried using :class_name, but it throws this exception:

    SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.game_id: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."game_id" = 2 LIMIT 1

Comment: could you add your user model as well as your table structure for user as well as game ?